# JSON loading ProgressView

Tags: ios, iphone, json, progress-bar

I would like to make a UIProgressView when i load some data from JSON.
Thats the code i am using to get the JSON data:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == searchTextField)
    {
        [searchTextField resignFirstResponder];
        [self loadData];

    }

    return YES;
}



-(void)loadData
{

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mydomain.com/search/getEvents.php?searchQuery=%@", searchTextField.text];
    NSURL *searchURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:searchURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

    });
}


-(void)fetchedData:(NSData*)responseData
{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    [fetchedResutsArray release]; // release old instance
    fetchedResutsArray = [[json objectForKey:@"Events"] retain];

    NSLog(@"%@", fetchedResutsArray);

    if (fetchedResutsArray != nil)
    {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    else if (fetchedResutsArray == nil)
    {
        UIAlertView *noResultsAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Results" message:@"There are no results" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [noResultsAlert show];
        [noResultsAlert release];
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me to create a progressview which displays the current download progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MBProgressHud](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) 
When you want to add/show Progress hud on your view just call
 
`[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];`
Then for hide/stop you can call
`[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];`

Comment: @profidash_98 Ok... If u have any problem related to this just ask